# Matrix 2.6.1 not working with EE revisions

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic, revisions

We have an older version of EE (2.5.1) and Matrix was not saving standard EE revisions of an entry.

The field was upgraded to the latest (2.6.1), but it's still not saving any revised data. This is true for both editing an existing cell/row or adding a new row.

The changelog suggests that EE revisions issue was resolved with Matrix version 2.5.5 and 2.5.6 (https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/changelog.html).

Both EE cache and browser cache was released before testing.

Has anyone else had this issue? If so, how can it be resolved?

Comment: Had a support request along the same lines. Boiled down to not working correctly on EE up to 2.9.0, but working as expected on EE 2.9.2. Go figure.

Comment: Hey Andris -- thanks for the reply. So we'll need to upgrade to 2.9.2 to have this work, right?

Hope you're well :)

Comment: Jae, I'll go with "probably, yeah" :)